# How to pass parameter to another page by TempData in ASP.NET MVC framwork?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, parameters, controller, action, tempdata

I want to Redirect from a page to another page without showing parameter on the url.

some articles say that "TempData is stored in the session and will be automatically removed at the end of the first request." recommand me to use TempData to transfer parameter, but it's not working so fine for me.

As you can see, this is a totally new testing project without any other noise, after `TempData["test"] = "testString"` executed, when I look into TempData, it has keys count and values count equal to 1,

but after `RedirectToAction("About")` has been executed, `TempData["test"]` has only both 0 count of keys and values.

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    TempData["test"] = "testString";
    return RedirectToAction("About"); 
    //return View("About", test); // this will show parameter on the url
}

public IActionResult About()
{
    string test = (TempData["test"] == null) ? "isNull" : TempData["test"].ToString();
    return View();
}
```

I've tried .Netframwork 4.5 and .Netframwork 4.8.

Actually, It works in Edge, and neither Chrome, Firefox or Opera does on my computer. But it works on my friend's computer in Chrome, we are confusing with these results.

Comment: You can test to call: TempData.Keep() to keep all the values of TempData in a third request.

Comment: hi, TempData.keep() does work. And I finally find out why it wasn't worked fine in my other project, Architect set the SessionStateBehavior to be ReadOnly, since that TempData is based on Session, it can't accept the data you push, and it doesn't report an error, it just abandon your data after you leave current function.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to check for null here (on very first read from tempData framework mark this for deletion). So in short in your about action use follow

```cs
object testValue = TempData["test"];
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check whether temp data is null or not you can use           TempData["test"].ToString()!=null and I think you cannot check Tempdata["test"] is null or not.

Comment: hi, although I'm not mean to check whether TempData["test"] is or not null, I think you will get crash instantly when you try to use a null doing ToString() method.

Answer (score 0):

```
string test = TempData["test"]  as string;
            if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(test))
                test = "isNull";
```

Comment: Please also describe how your solution addresses the OP's problem :)

Comment: person person = TempData["person"]  as person;
            if(person !=null)
                ...